# How to find non-matching records between 2 tables not having any unique keys

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables tblBudget and tblActuals.

tblBudget

```
 ProjID ExpenseType OrigBudget
 101    Furniture   5000
 102    Hardware    2000
 102    Software    3500
```

tblActuals

```
ProjID ExpenseType ActualExpense 
101    Furniture    4000
101    Hardware     2500     
102    Hardware     1500
```

I want to pull the matching and non-matching records into a single query so that it shows like this

```
ProjID  ExpenseType  OriginalBudget   ActualExpense
101     Furniture     5000            4000          
101     Hardware         0            2500
102     Hardware      2000            1500
102     Software      3500               0
```

I tried a join query which successfully selects the matching records but having trouble in selecting the non-matching records. My table **does not** have primary keys nor can they be added since its part of a huge company db.
Any help from left join experts will be highly appreciated

Comment: Please edit your question and post your query.

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `Access`?  Are the `ExpenseType`s stored somewhere or just randomly inserted in the table?

Comment: To format as `code`, select the text and press `ctrl-k`  or add 4 spaces before each line

Comment: Join doesn't depend on PK existence. You want FULL OUTER JOIN on ProjID   ExpenseType columns

Comment: @Serg can you please give me a sample? I have tried full outer joins but they only fetch records from one table and when i do a union of the 2 outer join queries it does not give me the desired result

Comment: @siyual, I am using Access. I usually store expense types in a table but very often i get new expense types which need to be added so the ones in this table are not always updated

Comment: Scrap Access, get a real database (or just use Excel if you have no primary keys anyway you basically have a big slow spreadsheet :S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access does not make this easy.  But here is one approach that should do what you want:

```
select b.ProjId, b.ExpenseType, b.OriginalBudget,
       nz(a.ActualExpense, 0) as ActualExpense
from tblBudget as b left join
     tblActual as a
     on b.ProjID = a.ProjId and b.ExpenseType = a.ExpenseType
union all
select a.ProjId, a.ExpenseType, 0 as OriginalBudget, a.ActualExpense
from tblActual as a left join
     tblBudget as b
     on b.ProjID = a.ProjId and b.ExpenseType = a.ExpenseType
where b.ProjId is null
```

Comment: I think you need left and right join with coalesce, But I made mine answer when thought rdbms was mySql

Comment: First join should also be a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. I noticed you didn't put a where b.projID is null condition on the first select query. I thought for the first query it would be b.projectid is null and for the second it would be a.projid is null ? am i right or plain wrong.

Comment: @Anup . . . The first query does the full `left join`.  The second adds in the rows not picked up by the first.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql use `LEFT/RIGHT JOIN` to emulate `FULL OUTER JOIN`

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/TYSFZ53545)**

```
SELECT tB.ProjID,  tB.ExpenseType,  tB.OrigBudget as OrigianlBudget,  
       COALESCE(tA.ActualExpense,0) as ActualExpense
FROM tblBudget tB
LEFT JOIN tblActuals tA
  ON tB.`ExpenseType` = tA.`ExpenseType`
 AND tB.`ProjID` =  tA.`ProjID`

 UNION  

SELECT COALESCE(tB.ProjID, tA.ProjID),  
       COALESCE(tB.ExpenseType, tA.ExpenseType),  
       COALESCE(tB.OrigBudget, 0),
       tA.ActualExpense
FROM tblBudget tB
RIGHT JOIN tblActuals tA
  ON tB.`ExpenseType` = tA.`ExpenseType`
 AND tB.`ProjID` =  tA.`ProjID`
ORDER BY `ProjID`
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]